# PowerShell End time of script execution

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write the start and end-date of this script in a logfile. The startdate is not a problem, but the end-date is apparently not written to the log.

```powershell
$Target = "\\share\dir1\dir2"

# Set start time
$StartTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $Target | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) } | % {
        $folder = $_;
        Remove-Item $folder.FullName -Recurse -Force | Out-Null
        $folder.FullName  
        # Set end time 
        $EndTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()   
        } | 

# Write footer to log
Write-Output ($Footer = @"

$("-"*79)

   Start Time          : $StartTime
   End Time            : $EndTime

$("-"*79)
"@)

Out-File $Target\Auto_Clean.log -Append -InputObject $Footer

# Clean up variables at end of script
$Target=$StartTime=$EndTime = $null
```

Thanks to the help from the guys here at Stackoverflow, I found the complete answer.

**Solution:**

```powershell
<#  Author: Me@site.com 
    ########## Remove folders older than x days
    2014/05/06 Script born 
    2014/05/07 Add total runtime of the script to the logfile #>

#================= VARIABLES ==================================================
$Target = "\\Share\dir1\dir2"
$OlderThanDays = "60"
$Logfile = "$Target\Auto_Clean.log"

#================= BODY =======================================================
# Set start time
$StartTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()

Write-Output "`nDeleting folders that are older than $OlderThanDays days:`n"

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $Target | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | ForEach {
        $Folder = $_;
        Remove-Item $Folder.FullName -Recurse -Force | Out-Null
        $Folder.FullName } | Tee-Object $LogFile -Append # Output folder names to console & logfile at the same time

# Set end time & calculate runtime
$EndTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
$TimeTaken = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime

# Write footer to log
Write-Output ($Footer = @"

$("-"*79)
   Start Time          : $StartTime
   End Time            : $EndTime
   Total runtime       : $TimeTaken
$("-"*79)
"@)

# Create logfile
Out-File $LogFile -Append -InputObject $Footer

# Clean up variables at end of script
$Target=$StartTime=$EndTime=$OlderThanDays = $null
```

Comment: Why would you put that inside the loop, and keep resetting it every time you remove a file, instead of just doing it once after the loop is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are trying to pipe nothing. you have a `|` after your foreach loop but all objects are captured within the loop, so there is no objects left for it to pipe. Just remove that pipeline character and it will work

Comment: You are right, for testing purposes I've put 0 instead of 60 days. Updated the question correctly now. But the problem stays the same.. EndTime (when the script finished) is not filled in in the logfile.

Comment: When I remove the final pipe after the Where-Object it does get the EndTime. However, the output of the removed folders '$folder.FullName' is not piped to the logfile anymore. So I now do get the dates correctly, but I don't get the foldernames anymore in the logfile :(

Comment: I just piped the ForEach again to the logfile with the Tee-Object command. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are coming across a scoping issue. The var `$EndTime` does not exist outside *foreach* loop so an easy fix is to define it at the top

```powershell
# Set start time
$StartTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
$EndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your final | from your where-object worked on my test. Also ensure that there is directories that meet your where-object as this will leave a blank end time also.

Comment: When I remove the final pipe after the Where-Object it does get the EndTime. However, the output of the removed folders '$folder.FullName' is not piped to the logfile anymore. So I now do get the dates correctly, but I don't get the foldernames anymore in the logfile :(

Comment: I just piped the ForEach again to the logfile with the Tee-Object command. Thank you for your help